# Alexa lernt ständig dazu - Pronominaladverb?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Alexa hat Skills – Alexa lernt ständig **dazu** und erhält neue Funktionen und Skills, zum Beispiel Fitness-Tracking, Spiele und vieles mehr.

Wird das Wort "dazu" als ein Pronominaladverb oder nur Adverb benutzt?

Comment: Warum die Frage? Was würde die Antwort ändern? So wie ich es sehe, stellen Promonialadverbien eh sowieso die Untermenge von Adverbien dar.

Comment: @Dan  Ich vermute, Ughi Tudhi hat das Unglück, an einem Sprachkurs teilzunehmen, in dem die Lehrperson auf traditionelle deutsche Schulgrammatik wert legt... eine fragwürdige Übung, aber gleichwohl eine verbreitete.

Answer (score 6):

Weder – noch. In diesem Beispiel ist es die abgetrennte Vorsilbe des trennbaren Verbs [*dazulernen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dazulernen):

> Alexa *lernt* ständig *dazu*.

Anders verhält es sich bei folgendem Beispiel:

> Bald ist die *Matheprüfung*. Alexa lernt ständig *dafür*.

Das Wort [*dafür*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/daf%C3%BCr) ist hier ein Pronomialadverb, das sich auf *Matheprüfung* bezieht, und nicht etwa die Vorsilbe eines trennbaren Verbs (<s>dafürlernen</s>).

Comment: Ist das Akkusativobjekt nicht notwendig für Verb "dazulernen" hier?

Comment: @ughitudhi, nein, ein Akkusativobjekt ist nicht notwendig.

Comment: ... wobei allerdings viele abtrennbare Verbteile sich aus Pronominaladverbien entwickelt haben. Man kann auch spontan neue bilden, und oft ist gar nicht klar: trennbarer Verbzusatz oder Pronominaladverb? Beispiel: _Man muss dazusagen / dazu sagen, dass viele Deutsche da auch nicht durchblicken._

Comment: @RalfJoerres, *„[...] und oft ist nicht klar: trennbarer Verbzusatz oder Pronominaladverb?“* Die Anmerkung verstehe ich nicht. Inwiefern soll da oft Unklarheit herrschen? Falls das Beispiel zur Anmerkung gehören soll: hier ist *dazusagen* ganz klar ein trennbares Verb, und *dazu sagen* ist das Pronominaladverb *dazu* gefolgt von dem Verb *sagen*.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, diese Unterscheidung ist so unsinnig, wie sich dar über zu streiten, ob es *get off of ...* oder *off the horse* lautet--ist also relativ sinvoll, wenn es denn Spaß macht. Die Rechtschreibung trifft doch keine Aussagen über kognitive Linguistik. Wenn überhaupt müsste es andersherum sein. Kognitive Dissonanz liegt wohl vor, wenn man nichts *daraus* lernt und meint, man könne nichts mehr *dazu lernen*. Ich für meinen Teil würde *dazu* gern *dazulernen*--ist ein Satz den so niemand nie sagen würde. Warum wohl? Wieso nicht auch mal daazu dazuu lernen? Oder da zu da zu.

Comment: @Björn Friedrich: Bei _dazusagen / dazu sagen_ hat man in beiden Fällen einen pronominalen Bezug, das 'da' referiert beide Male auf etwas vorher Gesagtes. Wenn es dieselbe Bedeutung hat, wieso gibt es zwei Schreibweisen? Wegen der Betonung. Wieso gibt es beide Betonungen, obwohl dasselbe gemeint ist? Könnte das einen Deutschlerner verunsichern (wie heißt es denn "richtig")? Ich denke schon, und nicht nur den. Wieso kann man z.B. nicht sagen '_ Er hat nichts dazugesagt_', obwohl man sagen kann '_Man muss dazusagen, dass ..._'?